# In my template the values are not reloaded

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular. I tried to upload my code to Stackblitz to look for help when I call my dynamic modal. I am doing a function that I hope to call in any component to generate a dynamic popup in which I can dynamically change the header, body and footer of the popup.

The popup does not refresh the values I give it when I call it from the home component. How can i fix this?

This is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qothyw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing your service for each component. Doing so creates an independend instance for each component which exists only in the scope of that component. Remove the `providers: [AppService]` in your components and just provide the service in your module. That should solve your problem.

Here's a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bypyew)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass input parameters to your modal component, it works like html tag properties.

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#declaring-input-and-output-properties

So if in your modal component class you add this property:

```
@Input() myValue = defaultValue;
```

You can then call your modal component this way:

```
<my-modal-component myValue="theValueINeed"></my-modal-component>
```

Comment: If you change a component input, then it forces to redraw the component.