# Open modal form containing form created from ngx-formly from another ngx-formly form

Tags: json, angular, angular-forms, angular-formly

I'm currently using ngx-formly to dynamically create a bunch of Angular forms from JSON, which works really nicely. I have a peculiar use case where a custom button on a form, should open a modal dialog containing another form on click, which would also contain a form created using ngx-formly. The example I saw on the ngx-formly site use a custom button, and creates a custom component with .ts files, but I want to avoid that since I would have several forms doing this, and I don't want to create different components for this.

Is there a way to trigger a modal dialog from an ngx-formly form, to show the modal with ngx-formly form without having to create multiple components(.ts) files for them?

Comment: See if this helps you, where common model is opened from anywhere with dynamic data, That answer has both jquery version and ngx-bootstrap version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296973/to-reuse-html-content-in-angular-5/50298872#50298872

Comment: Thanks @BhushanBabar. That worked nicely. Can you add as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Welcome. I have added the answer, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Common Bootstrap Model with dynamic data

- **Example with jQuery:**
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-fh92s3

**modal.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalModel} from './modal.model';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

declare let $: any;

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

  modalData = new Subject<ModalModel>();

  modalDataEvent = this.modalData.asObservable();

  open(modalData: ModalModel) {

    this.modalData.next(modalData);

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

}
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalService } from './modal.service';
import {ModalModel} from './modal.model';

declare let $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './modal.component.css' ]
})
export class ModalComponent  {

  modalData: ModalModel;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {
    this.modalService.modalDataEvent.subscribe((data) => {
      this.modalData = data;
    })
  }

}
```

**calling this service from any component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalService } from '../modal/modal.service';
import { ModalModel } from '../modal/modal.model';


declare let $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ]
})
export class HomeComponent  {

  modelData = new ModalModel();

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {

  }

  open() {
    this.modelData.header = 'This is my dynamic HEADER from Home component';
    this.modelData.body = 'This is my dynamic BODY from Home component';
    this.modelData.footer = 'This is my dynamic footer from Home component';
    this.modalService.open(this.modelData);
  }
}
```

- **Example without jQuery i.e with ngx-bootstrap:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-modal