# How to pass data from component to ngBootstrap modal in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, ng-bootstrap

I have a table with data displayed using ngFor. I need to display an individual row data in a modal on click. i can log it in console by passing the row as click argument but not able to pass it inside the modal.

Assuming the table data is being fetched from a service and the modal is a template reference which is in same component file as the table.

Here is a fiddle created
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr8ud5

I have used angular 1.x and the data was passed through resolve. I am new to Angular and have never worked in ngBootstrap.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check if this answer helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431629/open-modal-form-containing-form-created-from-ngx-formly-from-another-ngx-formly/50442223#50442223

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing of data from your component to ngBoostrap modal can be done via Angular's [2-way binding](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel). It is actually the very same way you carry out 2-way binding on Angular 1.x!

I have made a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr8ud5-onedcm?file=app/modal-basic.html) for you.

First, on your model-basic.ts, you define your model for the modal. Then, you assign the `modalContent` model property with the table row data.

```
modalContent:undefined
  .
  .

open(content, tableRow) {
  this.modalContent = tableRow
  this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'});
}
```

On your modal-basic.html, you can use the {{ ... }} [template expression](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) to display the individual properties of your model on your modal itself.

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Details</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    id: {{ modalContent.id }}
    <br>
    first: {{ modalContent.first }}
    <br>
    last: {{ modalContent.last }}
    <br>
    handle: {{ modalContent.handle }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works now. I just had to save the passed argument in a variable in .open()
It was that simple

Comment: Cheers :) Glad to help!

Comment: Simple, straightforward solution and even avoided component creation.. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

just need to store the selected row in a variable which we can then display on the HTML

in your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr8ud5?file=app%2Fmodal-basic.html), change **modal-basic.html** to be:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let tableRow of table" (click)="open(content, tableRow)">
      <th scope="row">{{tableRow.id}}</th>
      <td>{{tableRow.first}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.last}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.handle}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Details</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    id:<u>{{selectedRow.id}}</u><br>
    first:<u>{{selectedRow.first}}</u><br>
    last:<u>{{selectedRow.last}}</u><br>
    handle:<u>{{selectedRow.handle}}</u>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<hr>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

in your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr8ud5?file=app%2Fmodal-basic.html), change **modal-basic.ts** to be:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  templateUrl: './modal-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
  closeResult: string;
  table = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first":"Mark",
    "last": "Otto",
    "handle": "@mdo"
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "first":"Jacob",
    "last": "Thornton",
    "handle": "@fat"
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "first":"Larry",
    "last": "the Bird",
    "handle": "@twitter"
  }
];

selectedRow;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content, tableRow) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'});
    //console.log(tableRow)
    this.selectedRow = {id:tableRow.id, first: tableRow.first, last:tableRow.last, handle:tableRow.handle};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create variable for modal data in component:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr8ud5-v8gknx?file=app%2Fmodal-basic.html)

Or you may create component for modal: 
modal-basic.ts

```
openModal(dataToModal) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.inputDataInModalComponent = dataToModal;
        modalRef.result.then(() => {});
        }, () => {});
    }
```

modal.component.ts

```
export ModalComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() inputDataInModalComponent: any;

    ngOnInit() {
         console.log(inputDataInModalComponent);
    }
}
```